# How do I attract more reopen votes?

Tags: support, question-answer-ban

I had got banned from asking questions from chemistry stackexchange at least a six months back and now I am looking to remove that ban from my profile. So, in this question which I had posted in chem m.s.e I tried improving it by edits and putting it in better phrasing but there seems to be no hope for getting it reopened, could someone advice on how to improve my question to the extent it becomes reopened?

[What does it mean to 'fuse' ores and why do we use alkali metals in the process?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/127591/what-does-it-mean-to-fuse-ores-and-why-do-we-use-alkali-metals-in-the-process)

Comment: You may want to add a link to the question you are talking about so that others can look it up.

Comment: pl check the edit I made

Comment: Actually I mostly think it could be reopened with some grammar touchups. Right now your writing is somewhat disjointed: it's jumping from one sentence to the other without much connection. It's usually a good idea to have some kind of flow, this makes it much easier for people to follow.

Comment: In the meantime of the ban, you could reach out "jee chemistry club" chat room.